# bigquery SQL to calculate the Start and finish times for a project schedule

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

```
ID  NAME    DURATION    START   FINISH  P1  P2  P3
1   A         14                         1      
2   B         15                         1      
3   C         15                         1      
4   D         12                         1      
5   E         22                         2  3   
6   F         14                         4  1   
7   G         9                          5  6
```

Need to develop a recursive big query SQL to calculate the Start and finish times for a schedule.
Note the schedule number of activities can vary
P1 , P2 and P3 are the Predecessor IDs to the row activity
an activity may have only 1 Predecessor or multiple Predecessor
The calculation for Start and Finish Columns is as follows
Start is equal to the greater value of  "2017-01-01" or the (Max (Finish of its Predecessors +1 ))
Finish is always a function of Start + Duration -1
The calculation is expected to be recursive until an answer is achieved.

The reason I need this in bigquery is to perform a simulation of the schedule by iterations of changing the duration values.
The Answer to the above Schedule is as follows:

```
ID  NAME    DURATION    START       FINISH      P1  P2  P3
1   A       14          1-Jan-17    14-Jan-17   1       
2   B       15          15-Jan-17   29-Jan-17   1       
3   C       15          15-Jan-17   29-Jan-17   1       
4   D       12          15-Jan-17   26-Jan-17   1       
5   E       22          30-Jan-17   20-Feb-17   2   3   
6   F       14          27-Jan-17   9-Feb-17    4   1   
7   G       9           21-Feb-17   1-Mar-17    5   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i was hoping to have the iterations made with one run of the query. Is it possible to use inline JS ... ?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL
It does all iterations in just one run using [`JS UDF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) 
This requires passing whole table's data into UDF so definitely subject for UDF [`limits`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) / [`limitations`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limitations) 
I doubt this solution can be of real practical value, but definitely interesting from exercising and BigQuery features exploring prospective

Also be aware of some assumptions made here to simplify JS code and focus on root of question. So assumptions are: all id fields are filled continuously w/o gaps starting with value 1 (you can improve this if you wish :o) )

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION y(arr ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING, duration INT64, start INT64, finish INT64, p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [], fin;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){result.push(JSON.parse(arr[i]))}
  for (w = 0; w < 40; w++){ fin = true;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(result[i].start == null) { fin = false;
        var x1 = parseInt(result[i].p1) - 1;
        var x2 = parseInt(result[i].p2||result[i].p1) - 1;
        var x3 = parseInt(result[i].p3||result[i].p1) - 1;
        if(result[i].id == result[i].p1) {
            result[i].start = 1; 
            result[i].finish = 1 + result[i].duration - 1;
        } else if (result[x1].start !== null && result[x2].start !== null && result[x3].start !== null) {
            result[i].start = Math.max(result[x1].finish, result[x2].finish, result[x3].finish) + 1;
            result[i].finish = result[i].start + result[i].duration - 1;
        } 
      }
    } if (fin) {return result}
  } return result;
""";
SELECT 
  id, name, duration, 
  DATE_ADD(DATE '2017-01-01', INTERVAL start - 1 DAY) start, 
  DATE_ADD(DATE '2017-01-01', INTERVAL finish - 1 DAY) finish, 
  p1, p2, p3 
FROM (
  SELECT rec.* FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING(t) ORDER BY id) AS data
    FROM `yourTable` t
  ), UNNEST(y(data)) AS rec
) ORDER BY id
```

You can test / play with above using below with dummy data (from your question)

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION y(arr ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING, duration INT64, start INT64, finish INT64, p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [], fin;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){result.push(JSON.parse(arr[i]))}
  for (w = 0; w < 40; w++){ fin = true;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(result[i].start == null) { fin = false;
        var x1 = parseInt(result[i].p1) - 1;
        var x2 = parseInt(result[i].p2||result[i].p1) - 1;
        var x3 = parseInt(result[i].p3||result[i].p1) - 1;
        if(result[i].id == result[i].p1) {
            result[i].start = 1; 
            result[i].finish = 1 + result[i].duration - 1;
        } else if (result[x1].start !== null && result[x2].start !== null && result[x3].start !== null) {
            result[i].start = Math.max(result[x1].finish, result[x2].finish, result[x3].finish) + 1;
            result[i].finish = result[i].start + result[i].duration - 1;
        } 
      }
    } if (fin) {return result}
  } return result;
""";
WITH `yourTable` AS (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT NULL id, NULL name, NULL duration, 1 start, 1 finish, 1 p1, 1 p2, 1 p3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,    'A',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,    'B',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,    'C',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,    'D',      12,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,    'E',      22,          NULL,       NULL,        2,    3,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 6,    'F',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        4,    1,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 7,    'G',      9,           NULL,       NULL,        5,    6,       NULL   
  ) WHERE NOT id IS NULL
)
SELECT 
  id, name, duration, 
  DATE_ADD(DATE '2017-01-01', INTERVAL start - 1 DAY) start, 
  DATE_ADD(DATE '2017-01-01', INTERVAL finish - 1 DAY) finish, 
  p1, p2, p3 
FROM (
  SELECT rec.* FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING(t) ORDER BY id) AS data
    FROM `yourTable` t
  ), UNNEST(y(data)) AS rec
) ORDER BY id
```

with result being

```sql
id  name    duration    start       finish      p1      p2      p3   
1   A       14          2017-01-01  2017-01-14  1       null    null     
2   B       15          2017-01-15  2017-01-29  1       null    null     
3   C       15          2017-01-15  2017-01-29  1       null    null     
4   D       12          2017-01-15  2017-01-26  1       null    null     
5   E       22          2017-01-30  2017-02-20  2       3       null     
6   F       14          2017-01-27  2017-02-09  4       1       null     
7   G       9           2017-02-21  2017-03-01  5       6       null
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail Berlyant for the answer. I have tried to make a few changes, please see my answer below. i am getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected token for at y(ARRAY<STRING>) line 4, columns 2-5.      I am not sure if my answer will make the query more efficient. need your advise.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail. your answer was intelligent

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not support recursive query
So you will need to orchestrate recursiveness by your own using [`client`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice

Below is demonstration of how to achieve this by running series of queries till all dependencies are resolved

> **Step 1**: prepare initial table - `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` (simple example taken here from your question)

[image]

> **Step 2**: run iteration query with destination table same as source table - `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` with Write Preference >> Overwrite table

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.duration, a.p1, a.p2, a.p3,
  start,
  DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL a.duration - 1 DAY) finish
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` a
LEFT JOIN `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` a1 ON a.p1 = a1.id
LEFT JOIN `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` a2 ON a.p2 = a2.id
LEFT JOIN `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` a3 ON a.p3 = a3.id
CROSS JOIN UNNEST([
  IF(a.id = a.p1, DATE '2017-01-01', ((
    SELECT DATE_ADD(MAX(finish), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    FROM UNNEST([a1.finish, a2.finish, a3.finish]) finish
    WHERE IF(a.p1 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a.p2 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a.p3 IS NULL, 0, 1) = 
    IF(a1.finish IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a2.finish IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a3.finish IS NULL, 0, 1)
  )))   
]) start
WHERE NOT a.id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id
```

> **Step 3**: check if still entries to calculate

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(1) still_to_iterate 
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
WHERE start IS NULL
```

If count here is greater than 0 – proceed back with Step 2 and so on, till still_to_iterate = 0

> Processing Example:

if you do those steps manually - below is what you get

**Iteration 1**
[image]

**Iteration 2**
[image]

**Iteration 3**
[image]

**Iteration 4**
[image]

Of course, for more realistic cases - number of iterations can be high and even though still can be done manually can become not productive very quickly!
That's where you can script above logic using [`client`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice or [`bq command line`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-command-line#run_a_query) along with some bash / awk / etc. magic

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. But what i was hoping for is to have the iterations made with one run of the query. Is it possible to use inline JS to create the temporary table that can iterate on itself instead of a destination table with a name same as source table?

Comment: as I mentioned - `BigQuery does not support recursive query`, so above is the best option you have

Comment: I posted another answer (the first one and second relatively big so I put second as a separate one) - take a look - have fun :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION y(arr ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING, duration INT64, start INT64, finish INT64, p1 INT64, p2 INT64, p3 INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [],

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){result.push(JSON.parse(arr[i]))}

  ----------
    result[1].finish= new Date(new Date('01-Jan-17').getTime()- 1 * 86400000)

  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){

if (result[i].p1 === ''){result[i].p1 = result[1].id}
if (result[i].p2 === ''){result[i].p2 = result[1].id}
if (result[i].p3 === ''){result[i].p3 = result[1].id}
  }
  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){

    result[i].start= new Date(Math.max(  new Date('01-Jan-17').getTime() 
                                                ,Math.max(result[result[i][result[i].p1]].finish.getTime() + 1 * 86400000 ,
                                                          result[result[i][result[i].p2]].finish.getTime() + 1 * 86400000 ,
                                                          result[result[i][result[i].p3]].finish.getTime() + 1 * 86400000 )
                                                          )
                                                          )


   result[i].finish=  new Date( result[i].start.getTime() + result[i].duration * 86400000 - 1 * 86400000 )
   } 

   return result;
""";
WITH `yourTable` AS (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT NULL id, NULL name, NULL duration, 1 start, 1 finish, 1 p1, 1 p2, 1 p3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,    'A',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,    'B',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,    'C',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,    'D',      12,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,    'E',      22,          NULL,       NULL,        2,    3,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 6,    'F',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        4,    1,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 7,    'G',      9,           NULL,       NULL,        5,    6,       NULL   
  ) WHERE NOT id IS NULL
)
SELECT 
  id, name, duration, 
   start, 
   finish, 
  p1, p2, p3 
FROM (
  SELECT rec.* FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING(t) ORDER BY id) AS data
    FROM `yourTable` t
  ), UNNEST(y(data)) AS rec
) ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for [**Scripting**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [**Stored Procedures**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) is now in beta (as of October 2019)

You can submit multiple statements separated with semi-colons and BigQuery is able to run them now.

> i was hoping for is to have the iterations made with one run of the query

So, now you can implement needed logic as one pure SQL script (no JS UDF involved and no manual iteration) as in below example

```
DECLARE cnt INT64;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT NULL id, NULL name, NULL duration, CURRENT_DATE() start, CURRENT_DATE() finish, 1 p1, 1 p2, 1 p3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,    'A',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,    'B',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,    'C',      15,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,    'D',      12,          NULL,       NULL,        1,    NULL,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,    'E',      22,          NULL,       NULL,        2,    3,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 6,    'F',      14,          NULL,       NULL,        4,    1,       NULL    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 7,    'G',      9,           NULL,       NULL,        5,    6,       NULL   
  ) WHERE NOT id IS NULL;

LOOP
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS 
  SELECT a.id, a.name, a.duration, a.p1, a.p2, a.p3,
    start, DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL a.duration - 1 DAY) finish
  FROM temp_table a
  LEFT JOIN temp_table a1 ON a.p1 = a1.id
  LEFT JOIN temp_table a2 ON a.p2 = a2.id
  LEFT JOIN temp_table a3 ON a.p3 = a3.id
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST([
    IF(a.id = a.p1, DATE '2017-01-01', ((
      SELECT DATE_ADD(MAX(finish), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      FROM UNNEST([a1.finish, a2.finish, a3.finish]) finish
      WHERE IF(a.p1 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a.p2 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a.p3 IS NULL, 0, 1) = 
      IF(a1.finish IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a2.finish IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(a3.finish IS NULL, 0, 1)
    )))   
  ]) start
  WHERE NOT a.id IS NULL;

  SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp_table WHERE start IS NULL);
  IF cnt = 0 THEN BREAK; END IF; 
END LOOP;

SELECT * FROM temp_table ORDER BY id;
```

Above script ends up with executing 12 jobs - one parent and 11 child jobs

[image]

and if you will check result of final job - you will see resulted table

[image]